# Redirect to create page if CGridview is empty Yii

Tags: php, yii

I want to redirect to create page if Yii CGridview has no data in Admin page o/w redirect show CGridview with content.

Example:

Yii CGridview shows *"emptyText"=>"No data found"* for empty records then I want to write simple script to redirect back to create page.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Do you want it to be redirected when you are in controller action? I mean when you are passing dataProvider to your view then you want to redirect or situation is different?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose you are in actionAdmin and you are using CActiveDataProvider then you can write like this

```
$dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Post', array(
    'criteria'=>array(
        'condition'=>'status=1',
        'order'=>'create_time DESC',
        'with'=>array('author'),
    ),
    ),
));

if($dataProvider->totalItemCount < 1)
{
$this->redirect(where ever you want);
}
```

If you are using findAll then you can write

```
$models=YourModel::model()->findAll();
if(count($models)<1)
{
$this->redirect(where ever you want);
}
```

Comment: Great.. `$dataProviders->totalItemCount` worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Two lines are all you need. Put this in your controller action, just before `$this->render(...)`:

```
if(intval(YourModelName::model()->count()) == 0)
    $this->redirect('create');
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for ans... but I already used this buts not completely solving my issue. My grid is generating on different condition for different models so I need to check condition whether only gridview empty or not.

Answer (score 1):

You should do this in your controller. In your view you have

```
$this->widget('CGridView',array(
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
```

Perform the search in the controller, check to see if the CActiveDataProvider has no records returned, redirect if no records are returned. I believe you can use the getItemCount method of the CActiveDataProvider, see more here http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDataProvider#getItemCount-detail

Comment: On admin action I have added this condition `        if (!$model->findAll()) {
            $this->redirect(array('create'));
        }` but this case is not completely solving my issue.